# SQLite on Node.js: Reopeing a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite

I got a Problem with connecting to a database from two different functions in node.js.

At first, i connect to the SQLite DB to read some data out of it:

```
function getRbls(linie, stop) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    var db = openDB();

    var sql = someSQLString;

    db.all(sql, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        var rbls = [];

        if (rows != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                rbls.push(rows[i].rbl)

            }
            console.log("RBLs: " + rbls);

        } else {
            rbls = false;
        }
        resolve(rbls);
    });
    db.close();

});
```

This code works just fine and I had it running for a while now.

Now I wanted to implement a second function which always runs AFTER the first one is finished. To save some data in a different table:

```
function saveLastMonitorCall(rbls,userID) {
    var db = openDB();

//Has User a last call saved?
db.get(CountUserSQL,
    function (err, userCount) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var rblsString = rbls.toString();

        if (userCount > 0) {
            //User has a call in DB
            db.run(UpdateUserSQL,
                function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("User " + userID + " updated");
                }
            );

        } else {
            //User is new to DB
            db.run(InserNewUserSQL,
                function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("New User saved");
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```

The odd thing is that in the second function I get the error message on the first `db.get` :

```
SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file at Error (native)
```

The function `openDB();` has the following code which works fine for the first function:

```
function openDB() {
if (db) {
    return db;
} else {
    var sqlite = require('sqlite3');
    db = new sqlite.Database('./SQLite/StammdatenDB.db', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            //console.log(err);
            throw(err);
        }
        console.log("Connected to DB");

    });
    return db;
}
}
```

Anyone has a clue what the error could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You store the reference to the db in the `db` global variable (that's what I'm getting from the first lines of `openDB`), but then you call `db.close()` in the first function, not clearing the `db` reference.

Since this is SQLite and you are closing the connection immediately I'd drop the first part of the conditional in `openDB` and only leave what you have in the `else` block.